# I want to know Jenkins plugin update url

Tags: jenkins

I have installed Jenkins in my pc and I proceeded SetupWizard.
After unlocking, it was appeared to be offline. 
I was in company and it was blocked to out of company's network.(Something like fire wall)
If I know about url or ip-address of update site, I can proceed plugin installation. How can I know that?

Comment: I checked update center URL. (https://updates.jenkins.io/update-center.json) And I could connect the URL.(open or download .json file) But I could not update plugins. Error occured. javax.net.ssl.SSLException.

Answer (score 12):

The update center URL is by default http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/update-center.json

You find / configure this in *Manage Jenkins* > *Manage Plugins* > *Advanced*.

Answer (score 6):

The fresh default URL is https://updates.jenkins.io/update-center.json

In Web UI, menu path is the same: Manage Jenkins → Manage plugins → Advanced → Update site → URL.

Also you can get this value from shell, here is example for Debian/Ubuntu: `cat /var/lib/jenkins/hudson.model.UpdateCenter.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version='1.1' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<sites>
  <site>
    <id>default</id>
    <url>https://updates.jenkins.io/update-center.json</url>
  </site>
</sites>
```

or, for docker (here *myjenkins* is name of running container):

```sh
docker exec myjenkins cat /var/jenkins_home/hudson.model.UpdateCenter.xml
```

IP address, for March 2020:

```
 $ dig any updates.jenkins.io +short
mirrors.jenkins.io.
52.202.51.185
```

But IP address can be changed.

Comment: I have issues with updating plugins so I tried to open this url in Firefox to see if it's working. I got "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data". This isn't normal, right?

Comment: @Fred, yes, this is known Firefox error. Choose "Raw data" tab, or press Ctrl+U to see response without formatting, or use `wget` / `curl`.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that :-) Thanks for the heads up Alexey!

Comment: @Fred this is a JSONP. A proper JSON is also available at https://updates.jenkins.io/update-center.actual.json

Answer (score 2):

For plug in installation, you need to configure the proxy server information in jenkins

> Go to Manage Jenkins -> Manager Pluins  -> Advanced

Enter the Proxy server information, once updated Jenkins will be able to download and update the plugins.